# Angular 2 Copy Paste - Components

Tags: angular, dynamic, typescript, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to add a Copy Paste functionality (with events) in a web application developed in Angular 2.

The idea is as follows:

- User goes in 1 panel and selects which component he wants to copy.
- User goes into another panel and press paste.
- The aim is to be able to create a clone of the original component (with style, objects, child components etc.)

Much appreciate your guidance on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A component with the same Inputs will have the same appearence. So you don't have to worry about copying Component, but just the data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do I do this with Angular 2. I want to create copy paste buttons in the web page that lets me create copies of Angular 2 component in the browser itself